# WPF: Mahapps Metro Watermark is not showing up

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am working on a program, and in the settings I want watermarks to tell the user what he can insert there. I used Mahapps Metro, but the watermarks didn't show up, so I created a blank project with only one textbox, but it still doesn't show up.

My Code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="TestWater" Height="25" Width="200"/>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

The outcome:

[image]

(The background is actually "Wheat" to make the textbox more visible)

Am I missing anything why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Add this in the App.xaml of the your WPF Project.

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

I've tried this and this is working fine after this.

Go through the documentation provided [here](https://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html).